# She invited me to go with them, which I'd quite like to (do)

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, do-support, non-restrictive

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* , in **Chapter 17 Deixis and anaphora**, says (Page 1526):

[image]

Is [iv] well-formed? How about adding *do* after *to* as follows?

> *She invited me to go with them, which I'd quite like to **do**.*

Is the original version (without *do*) inferior to the *do*-version? Or are they equally natural?

Comment: No, it is quite common to end a sentence with to without the verb which, in context, is understood. — *would you like more ice-cream? I’d love to.* ***Prepositions, Ending a Sentence With*** https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with

Comment: @Hachi My question is specifically about the supplementary (aka non-restrictive) relative clause.

Comment: (iv) strikes me as UK, not US English. I've heard the construction, but I think I'd add a _do_, simply because I have an American accent and don't want to use UK phrases without reason.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one searches in the Corpus of Contemporary American English for a sentence that ends with:

which (pronoun) (verb) to do (full stop)

vs

which (pronoun) (verb) to (full stop)

by far the more popular variation is the one with *do* added, especially when one only counts the examples where the relativised element is a VP, and the antecedent is an infinitival functioning as catenative complement.

The same is also true of the British National Corpus.

So, as far as acceptability is concerned, both seem ok. But, the construction with *do* would seem preferred, or at least, more common.

Comment: Could you show me some "which (pronoun) (verb) to (full stop)" examples? I couldn't find any.

Comment: _Some days my best doesn't feel good enough but that's a result of me comparing myself to others, which I need to_ (BLOG   http://haveasliceofkatypie.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/it-has-been-a-while/ ) _You know what? I can honestly tell you for the first time in my life, in the last, you know, like, four years, I do not think some secret, dark knight's going to come and, like, pounce on me, which I used to_ (SPOK:CBS 2013)

Comment: _I think she's going to go a long way -- which she deserves to_ (Folly's child. Tanner, Janet. London: Century Hutchinson, 1991, pp. 13-124.)

Comment: _I wish I could do something to turn it around, which I'm starting to_ (SPOK: NPR_Weekend , The New Book 'Crews' Tells Of Life in a Gang, 1995)

Comment: Thanks for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there is an issue with the sentence as it is. Ending a sentence on a preposition is fine if you have already said what would normally come next (or somebody else has).

All of the other examples could be re-written like this:

- I still intend to submit a formal complaint.
- Would you like to have a stopover in Singapore?
- It's not clear she'll be able to finish her thesis this year.

The problem with the final example is the use of "which". You can't say "*... **which** I'd like to **go***".

Adding "do" makes more sense because the verb works in the context.

Alternatively, you could also say:

> She invited me to go with them, **and** I'd quite like to.

Comment: Either way, to is an infinitive marker in these cases, not a preposition.

Comment: Do you speak British English? @JohnLawler suggests [iv] sounds like BE. But it doesn't seem to work for you either.